# Using only TXD, without RXD?

Tags: uart, serial-console

Can you use the TXD pin by itself, so that the UART is read only from the RXD on the device it is being sent to?

My plan is to have a transistor on the RXDI (RXD in) pin of the Pi that can be turned on and off so I can stop any writing to the Pi from the external device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RXD, or TXD, or RXD and TXD.  I.e. you can use any combination you choose.

You also need a ground connection.

Comment: Yep, I've got the ground connection!